# PHPmailer send e-mail only sometimes

Tags: phpmailer

Im using PHPmailer to send email if user enter his e-mail. But sometimes (1/2 of emails) i get an error:

```
2013-10-15 11:12:39 SERVER -> CLIENT: 555 sorry, too many emails (#5.7.1)
2013-10-15 11:12:39 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 555 sorry, too many emails (#5.7.1)
2013-10-15 11:12:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2013-10-15 11:12:39 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2013-10-15 11:12:39 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
SMTP connect() failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of my project I also experienced this error. You reached the limit of emails you're allowed to send for this mailserver (preventing its usage as spam server). You could implement a queue to spread sending the mails over a given time or you could try to find another mail server. Mail servers of Internet Providers usually have good sending rates.

Comment: @user2075220 Id not recommend that. mail() is likely to get your mails end up spam folders and sometimes even get rejected when sent.